# How to use unicode characters like "heart" ♥ symbols in csv that Excel will read properly PHP

Tags: php, csv

How can I write csv file having unicode characters like "x♥x♥".

I tried 
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("content-type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8");

but it convert characters as "xâ™¥xâ™¥".

Comment: Where are the characters originating from? It may be an encoding issue *before* your output.

Comment: Is PHP writing the file with the correct encoding?